# An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions-After deploying to azure

Tags: c#, .net, azure, sockets, automationanywhere

At port "81", i have automation anywhere control room and want to make a api call to get authentication token.I tried below code locally its working fine but when i deploy in azure app service getting error

```
              using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
                   {                     
                       var authenticateClient = new RestClient("ipaddress:81/v1/authentication");
                       var authenticateRequest = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
                       authenticateRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", AAConstant.fileFormat);

                       authenticateRequest.Parameters.Clear();

                       authenticateRequest.AddJsonBody(new
                       {
                           username = "******",
                           password = "*******"
                       });
                       IRestResponse authenticateResponse = authenticateClient.Execute(authenticateRequest);
```

StackTrace :

```
   System.Net.WebException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1 creationTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DecompressionHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SendRequest()
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at RestSharp.Http.GetRawResponse(HttpWebRequest request)
   at RestSharp.Http.GetResponse(HttpWebRequest request)
```

Changed azure app service plan and also disabled antivirus,firewall but did not work .

Any help !!

Comment: I dont think you are allowed to use ports other than 80 and 8080?

Comment: @4c do you assert that an Azure App Service app can not connect out to any port other than 80 and 8080? Seems unlikely (and I know I have stuff on Azure that uses other ports, like RMQ, though they're all higher than 1024.. some low port prohibition perhaps?)

Comment: @Nandini where does this service on port 81 run? If it's running on a local/intranet host, have you accidentally deployed an internal-only ipaddress string?

Comment: @CaiusJard  i did not get you

Comment: You said: `new RestClient("ipaddress:81/v1/authentication");` - "ipaddress" is not an ip address. Tell us the real IP address in your code, please

Comment: @CaiusJard  its new RestClient(http:// http://192.168.225.30:81/v1/authentication);